# Apply multiple methods to a Clojure list?

Tags: clojure

I'm just starting out learning Clojure (my first Lisp-like language) so I'm sorry if this question is very silly.

I'd like to apply multiple methods on a list. So far I've come up with

```lisp
(defn sqr  [x] (* x x))
(def my-list '(4 7 9))
(map inc (map sqr (map dec my-list)))
;= (10 37 65)
```

Is there a better (more concise/idiomatic) way to do this? Ideally I'd like to do something like

```
(apply-multiple (dec sqr inc) my-list)
```

...which would also return `(10 37 65)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use function composition:

```
(map (comp inc sqr dec) my-list)
```

Or if you prefer to write them down in the reverse order (like in your example):

```
(map #(-> % dec sqr inc) my-list)
```

Comment: Coming from a Java/Scala world, the "dec sqr inc" form looked more 'natural', but I'm guessing "inc sqr dec" is more idiomatic for Lisp?

Comment: @sigint Yes, that's the usual order of function composition, as in mathematical notation (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). Most functional languages, including most lisps, adhere to this order. Some languages (notably F#) give you the choice by offering two different operators.